# webpack cannot find module "fs"

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, fs

I have a project that's using webpack and electron. I updated my app to use the latest version of electron as it was using electron-prebuilt. Since updating to the latest version I am now unable to compile my app due to this error. I've tried some suggestions from other SO posts which suggest editing webpack.config and added

```
node: {
fs: 'empty'
   },
```

I still get the same fs not found error. I also tried to set the target to electron, however when I do that I get a string of errors and none of my modules load, is there a workaround available for this issue? I'm not sure if this is a webpack related issue or an electron issue.

Here's my webpack.config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

//Loaders & Webpack config
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './app/app.js'],

  },

  output: {
    path: './app/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/'
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './app',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.jpg$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      }
    ]
  },

node: {
fs: 'empty'
   },


  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("^(fs|ipc)$"))
  ],


}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "factory",
  "productName": "Factory",
  "description": "",
  "author": ,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "bootstrap-css": "^4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "electron-packager": "^5.2.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.1.3",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/electron .",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "electron-packager ./ --platform=darwin,win32 --arch=x64 --prune --overwrite"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.37.2",
    "electron-tabs": "^0.6.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-onclickout": "^2.0.4",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: gotta set a target, mate, otherwise it will infer browser environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `target: 'electron-main'` in your Webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when working on NWjs with webworkers. First, make sure you set the right `target` option to "node-webkit", "webworker", "node", etc. Then, annotate the module like this:

```
externals:{
   "fs": "commonjs fs"
}
```

This will tell webpack to load it as a module, as opposed to assuming the dependency is already in the environment.

[webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) [nwjs](/questions/tagged/nwjs)

Comment: external "events"?7a7e:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined